# How to pull different lines based on values in first column to a new sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of entries in Google Sheets

```
1000 -- Johnny -- Ford  
1001 -- Mary -- Chevy  
1002 -- Jerry -- Toyota  
1003 -- Steph -- Chevy  
1004 -- Eddie -- Honda  
1005 -- Tim -- Ford
```

And I need to filter out only specific lines from a list of numbers on another sheet

```
1000
1002
1005
```

so that in a third sheet it reads

```
1000 -- Johnny -- Ford  
1002 -- Jerry -- Toyota  
1005 -- Tim -- Ford
```

So far I have tried "Query" and "Filter"

Comment: Are the numbers, names and cars in separate columns?

Comment: Yes... A1=1000, B1=Johnny, C1=Ford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:C6,"select * where A matches '("& textjoin("|",1,A9:A11)&")'")
```

A1:C6 is the total list of entries. A9:A11 contains the filter list of numbers.

```
=FILTER(A1:C6,REGEXMATCH(TEXT(A1:A6,"0"),JOIN("|",A9:A11)))
```

Although, Just `INDEX/MATCH` might do the trick.